priority of operations in function composition is backwards
I feel like the priority of function composition is backwards, and I would like to have a deep understanding of the phenomenon.
I do understand that function composition reads right to left:
$$(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x)).$$
This is "fine" (I guess we went too far down the road, and there is no way the notation $``xgf"$ will spread...).
But something even more backwards is going on (and independent of reading from right to left). I realized that when proving for the $n^{th}$ time associativity of function composition. At some point, we have the following equality
$$\left(f\circ (g\circ h) \right)(x)= f\left((g\circ h)(x)\right).$$
Again, I understand why it makes sense to do it so, and I am not questioning the "how" of why it works. But still, in the end, when we read
$$``f\circ (g\circ h)",$$
the parenthesis is saying that the second $``\circ"$ (the one of $``g\circ h"$) has priority over the first one, but when we apply it on $x$, the priority is somehow reversed: we first "break apart" the first $``\circ"$.
(the "problem" disappears after proving associativity, since after having proved associativity, parenthesis are no longer pertinent).
I would be happy with an intuitive answer and/or a more formal one, for example, in category theory vocabulary (I feel it has to do with contravariance, or maybe contravariance is only about reading from right to left...).

The parentheses in $f\circ(g\circ h)$ indicate precedence between the operation of composition, not how evaluation commutes with composition.

This has nothing to do with semantics and is entirely a matter of syntax and what we mean by "priority". The second $\circ$ "comes first" in the sense that, when building the expression tree from the bottom up, you start by building the $g \circ h$ subtree then proceed to parse the rest of the expression. The first $\circ$ "comes first" in the sense that it is at the top of the expression tree, so if you built it top-down you would start by splitting the expression at the first $\circ$ and then recursively parse the two subexpressions.
These are two ways of saying the same thing, i.e. they describe two ways of traversing the same syntax tree below. The difference is completely inessential.


What makes this correct answer clear is the reference to the expression tree. I hope that makes sense to the OP.

Thank you for the prompt answer! Could it be possible to explain a bit how the expression tree works in this case, and why it would not apply to associativity of addition for example?

I've added a diagram to my answer of the syntax tree for $f \circ (g \circ h)$ (treating $\circ$ as a primitive operation, rather than, say, a higher-order function that needs to be applied). I'm not sure what you mean by "it would not apply to associativity of addition".

It's actually incredibly common in certain fields for $f$ composed with $g$ to mean $g(f(x))$. Particularly in functional programming. Here's an example from Java:
x = Stream.of([1,2,3,4]);

f = u -> u * u
g = u -> u - 1
h = u -> u / 2

y = x.map(f).map(g).map(h)
// y[i] = h(g(f(i)))

What is most important is to understand the underlying syntax tree as how we understand what is truly going on in the situation. You may run into this situation in many code bases, though in pure mathematics writing you are far more likely to run into the opposite implied direction:
$(f \circ g \circ h)(x) = f(g(h(x)))$ as you mentioned. I just wanted you to know that the reverse way of writing function composition is absolutely all over the place and you will run into it. Always disambiguate which direction the author is meaning for composition to occur. It should be obvious from context.

Why the downvotes?
